# ContentEditable is not updating virtual DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, contenteditable, react-dom

I am facing an issue where contenteditable could not update the virtual DOM. if you see the below gif you will see that, by clicking on plus icon copy of selected item (which I edited) should be added at next to it, but copy of previous state of that element is being made.

The behavior I need is that by clicking on plus icon, copy of updated element should be made.

[image]

```
class TextInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let body = {bgColor:''};
        body.content = props.children ? props.children : '<span style="color:lightgrey !important; font-weight:light !important;">'+props.placeholder+'</span>';
        this.state = body;
    }

    focus(event){
        let target = event.target;
        target.style.outline = "2px dashed lightgray";
        if(target.innerText == target.getAttribute('placeholder')){
            this.setState({content:''});
        }
    }

    blur(event){
        let target = event.target;
        target.style.outline = "none";

        var html = target.innerHTML;
        if (this.props.onChange && html !== this.lastHtml) {
            this.props.onChange({
                target: {
                    value: html
                }
            });
        }
        this.lastHtml = html;

        this.setState({
            content:html
        });

        if( target.innerText == '' ){
            this.setState({content:'<span style="color:lightgrey !important; font-weight:light !important;">'+target.getAttribute('placeholder')+'</span>'});
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
        return nextProps.html !== ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.contentEditable).innerHTML;
    }

    change(event){
        let target = event.target;
        this.setState({
            content:target.innnerText
        });
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <div ref="contentEditable" contentEditable={true} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.content}} suppressContentEditableWarning={true} className="textarea" placeholder={this.props.placeholder} onMouseEnter={this.mouseEnter.bind(this)} onMouseLeave={this.mouseLeave.bind(this)} onFocus={this.focus.bind(this)} onBlur={this.blur.bind(this)}></div>
            <textarea onChange={this.change.bind(this)} name={this.props.name} value={this.state.content}></textarea>
        </div>;
    }
}

class EditorToolbar extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <div className="hoverbox-container">
            <span className="hoverbox">
                <i className="fa fa-plus" onClick={this.props.evCopyElem}></i>
            </span>
        </div>;
    }
}

class Body extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
           "summaries":[
              "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s. This is a new text.",
              "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
           ]
        };

        this.state.activeElement = -1;
    }

    mouseEnter(index, event){
        this.setState({activeElement:index});
    }

    copy_elem(type, index, event){
        if( type == 'summaries' ){
            let arr = this.state[type];
            arr.splice(index, 0, arr[index]);
            this.setState({ summaries: arr });
        }
    }

    render(){
        var that = this;

        return <div>
            {
                this.state.summaries && this.state.summaries.length ? <Container fluid>
                    <Row>
                        { this.state.summaries.map(function(element, index){
                            return <Col xs={6} className="mb-25" key={index} onMouseEnter={that.mouseEnter.bind(that, 'summaries'+index)}>
                                {that.state.activeElement == 'summaries'+index ? <EditorToolbar evCopyElem={that.copy_elem.bind(that, 'summaries', index)} /> : ''}
                                <TextInput name='summaries' placeholder='Enter Overview, Job History, Activities and Summary'>{element}</TextInput>
                            </Col>;
                        }) }
                    </Row>
                    <br />
                </Container> : ''
            }
        </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ref` to get the current value of the `textarea`. I did a small [repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3vcey2) and here is the code :

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default function App() {
  const textareaRef = React.createRef();
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState();

  const copy = _ => {
    setVal(textareaRef.current.value);
  } 

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea ref={textareaRef}></textarea>
      <EditorToolbar copy={copy} />
      <hr />
      Copied Value: {val}
    </div>
  );
}

const EditorToolbar = ({copy}) => {
  return <button onClick={copy}>Copy</button>
}
```